# ValueError: Could not interpret value `female_height` for parameter `x` when trying to plot certain rows

Tags: dataframe, seaborn

I have a big dataframe that consists of male and female shoe sizes. I am currently trying to plot size versus height for male and female separately. I have tried to slice the data and stored it in different variables, however I get an error when I try to plot it.

[image]

Here I tried to obrain rows that are only female height and shoe size

```
female_height = df.loc[(df[1] == 'F'), 3]
female_size = df.loc[(df[1] == 'F'), 2]
```

Here I tried to obrain rows that are only female height and shoe size

```
male_height = df.loc[(df[1] == 'M'), 3]
male_size = df.loc[(df[1] == 'M'), 2]
```

when I try to do the first plot only for female size and height I get this error:

```
sns.scatterplot(x='female_height', y='female_size', data=df)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I tested the columns and it displays exactly what I need, so what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

The code `sns.scatterplot(x='female_height', y='female_size', data=df)` is saying to plot the `female_height` and `female_size` columns of the dataframe `df`. But you have created separate variables called `female_height` and `female_size`, not created them as columns in your dataframe. If you plot these variables using `sns.scatterplot(x=female_height, y=female_size)` it should work.